# The Resistance in an electric kettle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, power

I have an electric kettle with two parallel heating elements, both with resistance $R_0=2\,\Omega $. Both can be independently shut on and off. There is also another resistor with resistance $R$. Upon using the kettle, I notice that there is no difference whether I use one or two heating elements, the same amount of water is heated in the same amount of time. How big is $R$?

[[image: Circuit Diagram of the kettle with a resistor r and two parallel heating elements <span class=]$R_0$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLRNs.png)

I have absolute no clue how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Think about it. The parallel combination of the two Ro resistors is 1 ohm. If there was no resistance R and your kettle were connected to a 120 vac outlet with both switches closed, if would draw 120 Amperes or 14,400 watts!!. What does that tell you R must be compared to Ro? But what I am really curious about is what does the manual say about the purpose of the two switches?

Comment: Does the heat from R also go into the kettle? Do any of these resistors have inductive reactance? I'm guessing that R is a current limiting inductor.

Comment: @BobD The OP is German, so the VAC will be 220 V, even worse! ;-)

Comment: Calculating the actual value of $R$ isn't possible without additional information.

Comment: @Gert Yes I am German and tired ;) Can I assume that the electric current is constant?

Comment: @P0lc3 Yes, you can assume that. But you can't determine $R$ without more info. E.g. the voltage over $R$. You don't know that. Latex is fine in comments.

Comment: @P0lc3 I converted my comment and your response to a formal answer.

Comment: You don't need additional information. Write expressions for the main circuit current, $I$, in both cases. Equate $I^2\times resistance$ for the heating element in both cases. You will find that the numerical value of the series resistance is an irrational number,

Comment: @PhilipWood So you're saying Bob D's answer is incorrect? But it's not. W/o **assuming** some power rating of the kettle (not included in the problem statement),  $R$ cannot be found.

Comment: I thought that the sentence starting "Upon using the kettle.." implied equal power in the kettle whether one switch is closed or both. And I'm assuming the supply voltage, $U$, to be fixed. That's all we need.

Comment: This yields $R=\sqrt 2\  \Omega $ if $R_0=2\ \Omega$.

Comment: P0lc3  I'd be interested to know the 'official' answer.

Comment: @PhilipWood sorry for the late answer, we were allowed to assume a constant voltage! Both answers were technically correct, I critized the task.

Comment: @P0lc3 "Both answers" Which are these?

Answer (score 1):

The parallel combination of the two Ro resistors is 1 ohm. If there was no resistance R and your kettle were connected to a 120 vac outlet with both switches closed, if would draw 120 Amperes or 14,400 watts!!. What does that tell you R must be compared to Ro? But what I am really curious about is what does the manual say about the purpose of the two switches?

> Is it even possible to find a concrete value for R, without imagining
> what outlet I am using? Because I now have the value of
> R=(RoU2+(-RoU1)/2)/(-U2+U1) (can I use LaTex in Comments?) Which would
> mean R highly depends on the Voltage I am using. Or is it wrong to
> assume that I, the amperage, is constant? About the manual, I have no
> idea.

You really can't get a concrete value for R simply on the basis of your subjective stated observation "I notice that there is no difference whether I use one or two heating elements". You can only say that R should result in a small enough difference in power dissipated for you not to notice the difference between one or two resistors Ro connected.

In any case, as I understand it most electric kettles consume about 1500 watts power. That's about 12.5 amperes for a 120 vac source. Using Ohm's law we can calculate the resistance R assuming a full load current of 12.5 amps.

$$I=\frac{120}{R+1}=12.5A$$

Which gives you R = 8.6 Ohms.

So if you have one Ro resistor switched on the total resistance would be 10.6 Ohms for a total power of 1358 watts and if you had two Ro resistors turned on the power would be 1500 watts, for a difference of 142 watts, or about 10% difference. Can't say, however, whether or not you would "notice" the difference without doing actual measurements of the time it takes to heat the water.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[image: voltage divider]

Assume both switches on the $R_0$ closed.

With the presence of $R$ the device can then be seen as a voltage divider, because:

$$U=U_1+U_2$$

$$U_1=\frac{U}{R+R_0}\times R$$

$$U_2=\frac{U}{R+R_0}\times R_0$$
The power dissipated by the $R_0$ is then:

$$P_2=\frac{U_2^2}{R_0}$$
$$P_2=\frac{U^2}{(R+R_0)^2}\times R_0$$
So the higher $R$, the lower $P_2$. Without a power rating ($P_2$) no value for $R$ can be determined.